# incremental update in HBase using sqoop

Tags: ssis, couchbase, hbase

i am working on a POC where i need to implement same like SSIS for sql to hadoop.
out DW are in SQL Server and we want to create a HBase at central location where all the data from diff DW will be posted. for the first time load i can do it using "sqoop import" command. but after then for changed data how to do incremental of sqoop with HBase?

Comment: Is this not answered in the Sqoop documentation [here](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.2/SqoopUserGuide.html#_incremental_imports)?